# Can't connect to database with php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to connect to my database via php but I keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error. It is hosted on GoDaddy. I'm fairly new to php. Here is my code:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect('server name', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('users', $conn);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
?>
```

Obviously I have entered my server name, username and password but not showing them here. I can't get it to connect at all. I wanted to be able to just to display a row of data on a page to check it works but I can't even get that far yet! I'm probably missing something obvious. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: **obligatory note** mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: The defunct `mysql_` extension doesn't support OOP syntax, e.g. `$conn->connect_error` you probably want `$conn = new mysqli(...);` (note the **i**) and `$conn->select_db(...);`

Comment: @CD001 Why don't you add this as an answer?

Comment: Can you edit your question with your PHP version?

Comment: @Mcload - because I'm fairly sure this is a duplicate question, I just can't be bothered to find it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons for getting 500 error on page and will discuss all of them below.

1. You have used `mysql_*` function to establish connection to database which is deprecated in newer version of php.
2. You may have issue with `.htaccess` code which is blocking you.

However you can check some points to figure out your issue.

Check your `.htaccess` file whether it is blocking you or not
Check your php version (If you php version is >= 5.5) then try below.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Hope this will help you!!

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I am no longer getting an error message, thank you! I have added "else { echo "Connected successfully"; } and I am getting that message. Thank you! I've tried to retrieve data from my database and echo it onto my screen but I receive the error again when I do so I'm typing something wrong.

Comment: $result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users");
 
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['id'].' '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['surname'].'<br/>';
    }

Answer (score 0):

you seems to be use the `mysql` as an `object` and it is not supported only `mysqli` that can behave like this . 
so if you need to use `mysql` extension and it is not recommend since it is deprecated.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect('server name', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('users', $conn);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
?>
```